# Python: How to get the length of itertools _grouper

Tags: python, group-by, python-itertools

I'm working with Python itertools and using groupby to sort a bunch of pairs by the last element. I've gotten it to sort and I can iterate through the groups just fine, but I would really love to be able to get the length of each group without having to iterate through each one, incrementing a counter.

The project is cluster some data points. I'm working with pairs of (numpy.array, int) where the numpy array is a data point and the integer is a cluster label

Here's my relevant code:

```
data = sorted(data, key=lambda (point, cluster):cluster)
for cluster,clusterList in itertools.groupby(data, key=lambda (point, cluster):cluster):
    if len(clusterList) < minLen:
```

On the last line: `if len(clusterList) < minLen:`, I get an error that

> object of type 'itertools._grouper' has no len()

I've looked up the operations available for `_groupers`, but can't find anything that seems to provide the length of a group.

Comment: There may be better ways, but you can convert the iterable to a list and count the elements (`if len(list(clusterList)) < minLen:`).

Comment: Thanks, RocketDonkey, that works perfectly!

Comment: No problem at all - the answers below suggest the same fix, so you can accept one of them to make it 'the answer'. Good luck with everything!

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Just because you call it `clusterList` doesn't make it a list! It's basically a lazy iterator, returning each item as it's needed. You can convert it to a list like this, though:

```
clusterList = list(clusterList)
```

Or do that and get its length in one step:

```
length = len(list(clusterList))
```

If you don't want to take up the memory of making it a list, you can do this instead:

```
length = sum(1 for x in clusterList)
```

Be aware that the original iterator will be consumed entirely by either converting it to a list or using the `sum()` formulation.

Comment: Such an elegant solution with sum!

Comment: `np.bool8(1)` (25 Byte) is smaller than `1` (28 Byte) on my system.

Answer (score 3):

`clusterList` is `iterable` but it is not a `list`.  This can be a little confusing sometimes.  You can do a `for` loop over `clusterList` but you can't do other list things over it (slice, len, etc).

Fix: assign the result of `list(clusterList)` to `clusterList`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cardinality package](https://github.com/wbolster/cardinality/blob/master/cardinality.py#L48-L52) for that. Method `count()` counts the number of items that `iterable` yields.

> cardinality: determine and check the size of any iterable

The following code gives you the length of `clusterList`

```
import cardinality
cardinality.count(clusterList)
```